# how do i generate unique question each time from list pool

Tags: python

what I was doing is generating five questions from a pool list of 20. so for generating those five questions, I was using random function. it works well most of the time, but sometimes it repeats the same questions in the pool of five. 
60% of the time the code runs fine it does generate random questions, it only a few times it repeats the same question twice. how do I improve this?

```
import random

questions = ["Traditional Maori food cooked in an earth oven: ",
         "Type in the Maori word for 'cave': ",
         "Something you eat to fill your belly: ",
         "What is 'Sun' in Maori: ",
         "A challenge laid down in chant and dance: ",
         "Visitor or guest: ",
         "A gathering, meeting, or assembly: ",
         "Funeral ceremony: ",
         "If you gave a donation, gift, or contribution, you would have given a...: ",
         "Maori word for 'Mountain': ",
         "What is 'Water' in Maori: ",
         "How do you greet in Maori like 'Hi, G'Day': ",
         "'Merry Christmas' in Maori: ",
         "Word for 'Winter' in Maori: ",
         "'Good Morning' in Maori: ",
         "Word 'Family' in Maori: ",
         "The most popular sport -'Rugby': ",
         "Word in Maori for 'Chicken': ",
         "'I am tired' in Maori: ",
         "Maori name for 'New Zealand': ",
          ]

answers = ["hangi", "ana", "kai", "ra", "haka", "manuhiri", "hui",
       "tangihanga", "koha", "maunga", "wai", "kia ora",
       "meri kirihimete", "takurua", "morena", "whanau", "whutuporo",
       "heihei", "hiamoe", "aotearoa"]

print("Welcome to Te Reo Maori Quiz!!!\n")
print("Answer the questions with single Maori Words.(Answers have to be in SMALL CAPS)\n")
x=0    `to store correct answers`
i=0
while i<5 :
    d=random.randint(0,19)
    user_answer = input(questions[d])
    if user_answer.lower() == answers[d] :
        print("Correct Answer!")
        x=x+1
    else :
        print("Incorrect Answer. The correct answer is: ",answers[d])
    i=i+1   
percentage = ((x*100)/5)
print("End of Quiz.\n", "Your Final Score is: ", percentage,"%")
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/isLNd.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add two lines at the end of the loop:

```
del questions[d]
del answers[d]
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than reinvent a sample algorithm, why not just use [`sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/random.html#random.sample) from the `random` module. You could do something like this to get 5 questions and answers together:

```
from random import sample

q = list(zip(questions, answers))
questions = sample(q, 5)
```

Giving you a random list of five question answer pairs:

> [('Traditional Maori food cooked in an earth oven: ', 'hangi'),
>    ("'Merry Christmas' in Maori: ", 'meri kirihimete'),
>    ("Maori word for 'Mountain': ", 'maunga'),
>    ("Word in Maori for 'Chicken': ", 'heihei'),
>    ("What is 'Water' in Maori: ", 'wai')]

Comment: Does it help with random function not generating the same number when the while loop is running.

Comment: 60% of the time the code runs fine it does generate random questions, it only a few times it repeates the same question twice.

Comment: Yes @ankurlakhanpal it helps with the problem. If you look at the link you will see: `Return a k length list of **unique** elements`